# How to detect when UIView has been drawn over

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a simple pixel drawing app. I have done some research but don't really know where to start so I have been looking at some examples in the developers site.

I am planning on creating a collection view of collection cells that when the user either touches or swipes around on the screen if that touch or swipe goes over one of the collection cells I would like to change that collectioncells background color to the current selected color.

these are the methods I plan to use.

```
#pragma mark - Touch Methods
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


}
```

however Im not sure how to detect if the touch intercepts any of the cells.
So my questions are

1, is using a collection view a good idea? as in the future I will allow the user to change the resolution from 8 16 - 32 bit etc.
2, How can I tell when a cell has been intercepted, touched or swiped over so that I can change the color of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UICollectionView has a method, indexPathForItemAtPoint:, which will give you access to the cell at a particular point, and UITouch has the method, locationInView: which will give you the point of your touch -- using these two methods together should be give you a good place to start.

As far as whether a collection view is good for this purpose, it's hard to say without knowing more about what you're trying to do. It is an easy way to get a lot of squares of whatever size you want on the screen, so I think it's probably ok.

Comment: It is hard to explaine what I am trying to do but I will try. But I want to create an application that the user can draw bit art in at their chosen resolution. so I would have an picker view that allowed the user to change the resolution 8x8, 16x16 and probably up to 32x32 views inside the container. I would then like to allow them to color in the squars by touching them. I will allow for the user to select the colors etc and lots of other stuff I havent even thought of yet my biggest issue was that I wanted to start it correctly. dose that help define what I am trying to do?